# Hash link disables relative link in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a webapp that basically its an one-page webapp so to link to another part of the app is like this:

```
<a href="#internet"></a>
```

This is possible because I used JavaScript that contains animations and different stuff, the problem is that somehow, this method disables the possibility to link like this:

```
<a href="internet/index.html"></a>
```

How can I have both links, without disabling the hash links?

**EDIT:** To be honest I dont know which part of the js its causing this behaviour because I took a template, but here is the js:

https://github.com/gomobile/template-list-view/blob/master/www/lib/appframework/appframework.ui.min.js

Comment: Well what is the JavaScript that is causing the problem?

Comment: you could add a class to the links that you want to go external, then check for class in js and if class exists on clicked element then do not prevent default

Comment: Please post relevant JavaScript code.

Comment: I already add a link with the js

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a code like this

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You need to have an if like

```js
if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') == 0) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

OR better change the selector to:

```js
$("a[href^=#]").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your animation here.
});
```

This code will just apply to anchor elements that have the href starting with #

------- update --------

You added a minified js :).
If you don't have the problem in your code, you can fix it with a hack like this:

```
$('a:not([href^=#])').on('click', function(e) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

But you should really find the issue, not fix it like this :)

Comment: Nice little lesson there on the perils of `prrventDefault`